# What Regular Expression can I use to remove all characters from a url after the last /

Tags: expression

When given a full URL I need a regular expression that I can use to replace everything after the final slash with nothing, i.e.

```
http:// www.somewhere.com/someplace/subsomeplace/default.aspx
```

would return

```
http:// www.somewhere.com/someplace/subsomeplace/
```

and

```
http:// www.somewhere.com/someplace/subsomeplace
```

would return

```
http:// www.somewhere.com/someplace/
```

The spaces in the URLs above are not really there I needed to remove them because Stack Overflow won't let me post more then 2 URLs

Comment: No need for a regular expression. Find the last slash and take the substring to that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/[^\/]*$/
```

This will give you the part you need.

Rubular link: http://rubular.com/r/zJlu1O5SqC

JavaScript example, tested in FireBug:

```
"http://www.somewhere.com/someplace/subsomeplace/default.aspx".match(/[^\/]*$/g);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working.  I'm getting the same full URL after running this

Comment: I've tested in the application that I'm using that accepts regular expressions and when that didn't work I went to http://www.regexlib.com/RETester.aspx and tested it there

Comment: Ah, my guess would be that you're entering the first and last "/" in to the input box on that site. Those denote a regular expression, but they should not go into that text field. Just use "[^\/]*$" there.